# Solving right-angled triangle with one side

Tags: trigonometry, pythagorean-triples

My teacher challenged us to get the sides of right angled triangle with one side.

> ABC is a right-angled triangle at B. AB is 6 cm long. Find AC and BC.
>   [image: Triangle]

Comment: My dear, that's impossible! Only one side and one angle?

Comment: Maybe your teacher asked about integer solution?

Comment: Is the triangle isosceles?

Comment: He said that the 2 sides is only integer numbers

Comment: BC=8, AC=10; it is a multiple of the celebrated 3,4,5 triangle. In order to show that it is the only possible triangle (I think so, but I'm not certain) use the formulas of the pythagorean triples.

Comment: Mahmoud, you should realise that this problem is impossible without the integer condition. So you must edit your question to include it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your teacher meant **integer sides** (otherwise it has an infinite solutions!!).

So,we can see that one side is $6$ units.

We know,$AB^2+BC^2=AC^2$.So,the three are Pythagorean triples.

We can generate Pythagorean triples in the following way.

$(m^2-n^2),2mn,(m^2+n^2)$ are three numbers which are Pythagorean triples for any integers $m,n$.

So,here we let,$2mn=6\implies mn=3$ Now,as $3$ is a prime it can be factorized only as $3\times1$.So,$m=3,n=1$.

Substituting these values into $(m^2-n^2)$ and $(m^2+n^2)$ we get $8,10$ respectively.So,the sides are $8,6,10$.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: All Pythagorean triples can be written as $(m^2 - n^2, 2 m n, m^2 + n^2)$; for example in $(9, 12, 15)$, $15 = 3 \pmod 4$ and so cannot be written as $m^2 + n^2$ for any $m, n$. But we *can* write every triple as a $(k(m^2 - n^2) 2 k m n, k (m^2 + n^2)$ for some integers $k, m, n$. We must also check whether the first factor, $k(m^2 - n^2)$ can be $6$, and indeed $k = m = 2, n = 1$ gives $m^2 - n^2 = 6$, but these choices produce the triple $(6, 8, 10)$, which yields the same triangle as the triple identified in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have been doing Pythagoras theorem on right angled triangles. First think about of the sides were string that is elastic. As you move C left or right along the horizontal your triangle still keeps its 90 degree angle and AB stays 6 cm. So just those two conditions have infinitely many triangles that satisfy them. Now since we have the 90 degree angle we can use Pythagoras to get length from A to C multiplied by itself is equal to the length from B to C multiplied by itself plus the length from B to A multiplied by itself. In formula form if we let the length from A to C be x and the length from B to C be y we have $ x^2 = y^2+6^2$ and so $x^2 -y^2 = 36$. Now you can write the left hand side as $(x+y)(x-y)$. So this tells you that since $x$ and $y$ are both whole numbers bigger than zero (since they are lengths) then $x+y$ must also be a whole number bigger than zero AND it also divides into 36 a whole number of times. So you can now get a short list of the only numbers $(x+y)$ can be. Then for each number on your list there is only certain pairs of whole numbers which when added together give you this number. These pairs are the only POSSILE values for $ x$ and $y$. However for each pair you have one more thing to check which is when you work out $x-y$ for that pair then it multiplied by ... has to equal ...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the given side AB (= 6cm) is the base of a right - angled isosceles triangle for which the other two sides are of three multiplied by square root of two (measured in cm.)

Comment: Why do you emphasize on $cm$?It can be any other unit.Also,it can be solved even if the triangle is not isosceles.Check out my answer below!!